# Solving $\sin(-\theta)=0.35 $. Is $\sin$ postive or negative? Where are the angles located?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My question:
$$\sin(-\theta)=0.35 \qquad\text{range: } 0<\theta<360$$

Is $sin$ positive or negative in this case? and where would the angles locate at?

Thank you!

Comment: Your pre-edit $-20.5^\circ$ and $-159.5^\circ$ are not in the interval $[0^\circ,360^\circ)$.  So you need to find the equivalent angles which are in that interval

Comment: @Henry is sin positive or negative?

Comment: $\sin$ gives positive values for angles between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$ and  between $-360^\circ$ and $-180^\circ$ and  between $360^\circ$ and $540^\circ$ and ..., while $\sin$ gives negative values for angles between between $-180^\circ$ and $0^\circ$ and  between $180^\circ$ and $360^\circ$ and ....  In general you have $-1 \le \sin(\theta) \le 1$

Comment: @Tfue: The question “is sin positive or negative” is meaningless. The sine of what? The value $\sin(-\theta)$ is obvious positive, though, since it's equal to $0.35$ by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these type of question, we should draw the graph of $\sin x$, and do some algebraic manipulation based on that. We know that $$\sin(-\theta) = -\sin(\theta)$$ therefore we are trying to find the solution of $\sin x = -0.35,$ where $x \in (0^{\circ},360^{\circ})$.

From the graph, we see that, $\sin(x)$ is negative in $x \in(180^{\circ},360^{\circ})$, hence we will have two solutions one in each of the intervals $(180^{\circ},270^{\circ})$ and $(270^{\circ},360^{\circ})$ (as it takes all values between $0$ and $-1$ in both of these intervals).

If you want better bounds on where the roots will lie, you should consider the increasing-decreasing nature of the graph and decimal values of the known values of sin function (For example, $\sin(x)$ takes values between $0$ and $-0.707$ for $x \in (180^{\circ},225^{\circ}),$ so $-0.35$ will occur in this interval between $180^{\circ}$ and $270^{\circ},$ which is a better bound).

Hope it helps:)